# Android Firebase: Stop Listening to A Query Passed To Adapter

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using FirebaseListAdapter that accepts a query in its constructor. I'm looking for a way to stop listening to the query after passing it to the constructor.

Here is where I create the query and pass it to the adapter:

```
        lvSportPics = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lv_pics);

    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    final DatabaseReference imagesRef = database.getReference().child(Constants.NODE_IMAGES);

    Query sportImagesQuery = imagesRef.orderByChild("sport").equalTo(sport);

    SportImagesAdapter imgAdapter = new SportImagesAdapter(getActivity(), SportImage.class,
            R.layout.list_item_sport_pic, sportImagesQuery);

    lvSportPics.setAdapter(imgAdapter);
```

and here is the adapter's constructor:

```
public class SportImagesAdapter extends FirebaseListAdapter<SportImage> {

public SportImagesAdapter(Activity activity, Class<SportImage> modelClass, int modelLayout, Query query) {
    super(activity, modelClass, modelLayout, query);
}
```

I know I can use valueEventListner, but I guess I need to loop through the results, and the adapter kinda does that automatically when passing the query. It works good, but it keeps listening to changes, I want a way to stop listening.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you need to remove the listener accordingly to the life-cycle of your activity like this:

```
databaseReference.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
```

If you have added the listener in `onStart` you have to remove it in `onStop`.
If you have added the listener in `onResume` you have to remove it in `onPause`.
If you have added the listener in `onCreate` you have to remove it in `onDestroy`.
But remember `onDestroy` is not always called.